# How to get ascending order of array values in seInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hi i used setinterval function to show some images. i am assigning the img src in array and then going through the array to show all images.But the problem is i used random option to pick & show img in each interval.

```
var set = setInterval(function(){test();},2000);

function test() {
  var img = new Array("red","green","blue","orange","yellow","balck");
  var src = img[Math.floor(Math.random()*img.length)];
  $(body).append(src);
}
```

Above code is sample i have tried

Now i want to come in ascending order like what order in the array same order i should able to see the image.

I thought about `for loop` inside the `setInterval` but that will show all images in each interval. i don't want that way. I want to get each image at each interval in ascending order.

setting any variable to 0 and incrementing it at the end also no use because once the interval finished it will again start another execution with 0 setted at the start of function.

is there any possible to calculate the number of interval has passed in `setInterval`, by that ecah image can be shown easily

Any idea to accomplish this?

Comment: please explain what you mean that you don't want it to start to 0 after each run. Do you want it to start at a random number and then loop through all of them?

Comment: please explain what you mean that you don't want it to start to 0 after each run. Do you want it to start at a random number and then loop through all of them?

Comment: first run 0 then second run 1 then third run 2 then fourth run 3...so on after the array is finished then again it should start from 0 1 2 3...

Comment: That's what the people below are telling you to do.

Comment: i have a doubt every time the function finished with interval then again it will start from zero right

Comment: No, because they have created the variable out of the `setInterval` function, which will keep its value, and when `setInterval` runs again, it will continue from where it stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use global `variable` and increament it to present incremented `index` of array. When index reached length of array you can set it to `zero` to make it cyclic.

```
var set = setInterval(function(){test();},2000);
currentIndex = 0;
function test() {
  var img = new Array("red","green","blue","orange","yellow","balck");
  if(currentIndex == img.length) 
      currentIndex = 0;
  var src = img[currentIndex++];
  $(body).append(src);
}
```

Comment: how the next image will come then

Comment: each interval each image should come @Adil

Comment: setting to zero will again start from 0 at each interval

Comment: There was typo, sorry about that I have increamented the currentIndex, please check my updated code.

Comment: thanks.i have doubt can you explain me in chat @Adil

Comment: At start the function get `currentIndex` value from global variable i.e 0. then it will go through the increment.again for second interval the function start at that time why it is not getting value from global variable, it is like fresh start of function. Thanks

Comment: It takes the value from global variable and it is changed from 0 to 1 for first iteration

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a var outside the function in the script block that will act as a global variable and then you can set it in the function and increment it after each call till the limit of the array is reached and once the limit reached reset to 0.

Comment: setting to variable to zero will again start from 0 at each interval